# Streamline two change function calls jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do my best to learn jquery and javascript and wrote two different change() functions that are the same but I feel can be more streamline and combined.

what do you guys think the cleanest approach is here?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                            jQuery("#custcolmen_size").change(function () {
                              if($('.stock-message > span:contains("Out of stock")').length){ 
                                    $(".add2cart-div > input").addClass('disabled').removeClass('cart');
                                    $(".stock-message > span").addClass('alert alert-danger');
                                }

                                else if($('.stock-message > span:contains("")').length) {
                                    $(".add2cart-div > input").removeClass('disabled').addClass('cart');
                                    $(".stock-message > span").removeClass('alert alert-danger');
                                 }
                            });


                            jQuery("#custcolwomen_width").change(function () {
                              if($('.stock-message > span:contains("Out of stock")').length){ 
                                    $(".add2cart-div > input").addClass('disabled').removeClass('cart');
                                    $(".stock-message > span").addClass('alert alert-danger');
                                }

                                else if($('.stock-message > span:contains("")').length) {
                                    $(".add2cart-div > input").removeClass('disabled').addClass('cart');
                                    $(".stock-message > span").removeClass('alert alert-danger');
                                 }
                            });

                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the logic of both handlers is the same you can join the two selectors together with a comma, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery("#custcolmen_size, #custcolwomen_width").change(function () {
        if ($('.stock-message > span:contains("Out of stock")').length){ 
            $(".add2cart-div > input").addClass('disabled').removeClass('cart');
            $(".stock-message > span").addClass('alert alert-danger');
        }
        else if ($('.stock-message > span:contains("")').length) {
            $(".add2cart-div > input").removeClass('disabled').addClass('cart');
            $(".stock-message > span").removeClass('alert alert-danger');
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem i'm having now is if you select the size first then the width and the item is out of stock it works great. but if you for some reason select the width first and then the size it doesn't work.

Comment: normally we select dropdowns top to bottom but what if we select them bottom to top?

Comment: I don't see how the order of events makes any difference as your original example is running the exact same code in both cases. Logically this is no different. Could you setup an example of the code in a http://jsfiddle.net so I can see how it actually works.